# How to use service account instead of web application for google drive api

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

The following javascript code uses web application account to access the drive api. I need some help in modifying the code so that it can uses service account for the whole application instead of web application account so that one does not need to log in to the particular gmail account to retrieve the files from google drive.

It would be really helpful if someone could point out what part on the code should be changed to use service account and still retain the functionality of retrieving files from google drive.

```
 <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("cerebra", $con);
$sql="select name from details order by download desc limit 20";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
$query=mysql_query($sql,$con);
$names=array();
$index=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $names[$index]=$row[0];
    $index++;
}
foreach($names as $a)
echo $a;
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var CLIENT_ID = '106997880011-je955vl71s3hbj7vh03oh1df1h5l9u9q.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var API_KEY = 'AIzaSyDYksh35q9jS1_YumnjWYR-717AoCKSXhM';
var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';



    function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
    }

    function checkAuth() {
        var options = {
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: SCOPES,
            immediate: true
        };
        gapi.auth.authorize(options, handleAuthResult);
    }

    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
       <!-- var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');

        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
            <!--authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            makeApiCall();
        } else {
         <!--   authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
           handleAuthClick;
        }
    }

    function handleAuthClick(event) {
        var options = {
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: SCOPES,
            immediate: false
        };
        gapi.auth.authorize(options, handleAuthResult);
        return false;
    }

    function makeApiCall() {  
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', makeRequest);   
    }

    function makeRequest() {
        var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list();
        request.execute(function(resp) {          
            for (i=0; i<resp.items.length; i++) {
                var titulo = resp.items[i].title;
                var fechaUpd = resp.items[i].modifiedDate;
                var userUpd = resp.items[i].lastModifyingUserName;
                var userEmbed = resp.items[i].embedLink;
                var userAltLink = resp.items[i].alternateLink;
                var download = resp.items[i].webContentLink;
                var hold="Download";

               <!-- var fileInfo = document.createElement('li');
              <!--  fileInfo.appendChild(document.createTextNode('TITLE: ' + titulo + ' - LAST MODIF: ' + fechaUpd + ' - BY: ' + userUpd +'  url:  ' + hold.link(download)));                
               <!-- document.getElementById('content').appendChild(fileInfo);

                document.write(titulo + "&nbsp;");
                document.write(hold.link(download) + "<br>");

            }
        });    
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
     <!-- $('#authorize-button').on('click', 
      handleAuthClick;
      $.getScript('//apis.google.com/js/api.js', function() {
        gapi.load('auth:client', handleClientLoad);
      });
    });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You can only made files public accessible but you cannot crawl for public files on the client-side, to do this you need to logon first. If you want to make public content visible to users without login, you need to create a back-end (for eaxample in PHP) for it, otherwise it is not possible/allowed to crawl for new content.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my blog - I've just finished an article about similar use case - examples are for Java server side logic but there is detailed general explanation of particular steps that are common for all server side languages:

http://devmint.blogspot.cz/2013/03/access-application-google-drive-account.html